# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 with interface controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, watchkit

I am starting to develop my new application with WatchKit.

In the WatchKit Extension, I have 2 interface controllers. When I import my `AppDelegate` in both `.h` files of these 2 interface controllers I receive the following error :

```
'Id: 30 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64'
```

These 30 symbols come from my `appDelegate.h`

When I remove '`#Import "AppDelegate.h"` from either one of the `.h` files of the 2 interface controllers the issue goes away.

However, new issues appear as I use values that are defined in my `AppDelegate.h`

Finally, I can't import `AppDelegate.h` in both files but new issues appears if I don't (which proves that I don't import twice `AppDelegate.h`).

**NB:** I did the same with `ViewController` for the iPhone version of my app and everything works fine.

Any hint from where the issue may come from ?

Thanks

**EDIT for bgilham**:

-Can't see a '`.m`' file

-I don't use the `-Obj` linker flag

-Different names in my iOS and WatchKit targets

-I use the same constant (defined in `appdelegate.h`)

I do think it is related to `AppDelegate.h` as it happens only with this file and not another one.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check:

- Make sure you haven't imported a `.m` file somewhere by mistake.
- Check for anywhere that you may inadvertently be importing something twice.
- Are you using the `-Objc` linker flag? This causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category.
- Do you have any files with the same name in your iOS target *and* your WatchKit target?
- Any constants with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you are using xcode 6 or 7. The problem is that in those new versions, variables' names must be different from each class.

I suggest you that replace each variable name adding a different number at the end of the name.